# Using list comprehension to search the first element of each element in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm comparing two lists to find if new data has been added to database 'polo'.

Originally the lists took the same form, however now 'excel' needs an accompanying coordinate to it's value. This was this orignal LC:

```
[x for x in polo_list if x not in excel]
```

I'm fascinated to hear about the different ways we can solve this (maybe I'm taking the wrong approach), here's a sample of the code now:

```
excel = [ ['a','a4'],['b','z4']]
polo = ['a','b','d']

a = [x for x in polo if x not in excel]

print 'new data! ', a

#should print,'new data!' ['d']
```

Thank you for your time

EDIT: Ah fantasic ! it's seems so simple now ! thank kind stackoverflow community, I freakin' love this site

Comment: "`#should print,'new data!' ['b']`" Do you mean "`['d']`"?

Comment: Shouldn't the output is `'d'`?

Comment: `excel` is a list of lists ..

Comment: @IronFist - Yes, and that's why the previous approach is no longer adequate.

Answer (score 5):

Just search in another comprehension:

```
a = [x for x in polo if x not in [item[0] for item in excel]]
```

It's better to save those values beforehand, though:

```
excel_first = [item[0] for item in excel]
a = [x for x in polo if x not in excel_first]
```

Or with a `set`:

```
excel_first = {item[0] for item in excel}
a = [x for x in polo if x not in excel_first]
```

Or, even better, with a dictionary:

```
excel = dict(excel)
a = [x for x in polo if x not in excel]
```

`excel` will then be a dictionary that you can use to quickly look up coordinates.

Comment: Are you sure about `dict(excel.items())`? Isn't `excel` a list?

Comment: I don't know why I saw a dictionary there, as the whole point was to turn it into one. Thanks.

Comment: Wow this is amazing, make a dictionary out of the list then we simply iterate through the list (as iterating though a dictionary gives on the key). Simply beautiful

Comment: EDIT: i don't i think i need the .items() ? simple excel = dict(excel) makes the code work, any discrepancies with this ?

Comment: @DavidHancock - Yes, sorry, the `.items()` was a mistake. Just use `excel = dict(excel)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest use two list comprehension here:

```
>>> excel = [['a', 'a4'], ['b', 'z4']]
>>> polo = ['a','b','d']
>>> [x for x in polo if x not in [i[0] for i in excel]]
['d']
```

`[i[0] for i in excel]` generates a new list which is `['a', 'b']`, it loops over `[['a', 'a4'], ['b', 'z4']]` and gets the element from it which the index is `0`.

Anyways, if you have duplicate *keys* in `excel` for example it's `[['a', 'a4'], ['b', 'z4'], ['b', 'z5'], ['b', 'z7']]`, the output of `[i[0] for i in excel]` will be `['a', 'b', 'b', 'b']`.

Since these `'b'`s are useless, we can use a set comprehension instead:

```
>>> excel = [['a', 'a4'], ['b', 'z4']]
>>> polo = ['a','b','d']
>>> [x for x in polo if x not in {i[0] for i in excel}]
['d']
```

---

You can also forget list comprehension and compare sets instead like below:

```
>>> excel = [['a', 'a4'], ['b', 'z4']]
>>> polo = ['a','b','d']
>>> set(polo) - {i[0] for i in excel}
{'d'}
```

Remember that this way doesn't keep order and duplicate keys.

Answer (score 1):

Here [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.chain) can help:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x for x in polo if x not in chain(*excel)]
['d']
```

> ```
> chain(*iterables) --> chain object
> ```
>
> Return a chain object whose `.__next__()` method returns elements from the
>   first iterable until it is exhausted, then elements from the next
>   iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.

Comment: I was going to post exactly the same answer :D . Anyway, +1

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Happened to me many times. Often it is just a question of seconds. But it indicates that it is a useful approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it with `filter` and `chain` :

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> filter(lambda s:s not in chain(*excel), polo)
['d']
```

Another way with `itemgetter` and `map`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [x for x in polo if x not in map(itemgetter(0),excel)]
['d']
```

Or:

```
>>> [x for x in polo if x not in (itemgetter(0)(x) for x in excel)]
['d']
```